# Rails opposite of db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```

This command is used to migrate the scaffold generated models to the database.
What is the procedure to generate the models using the database.

Comment: Are you starting with an existing database schema?

Comment: the awser can be found [in existing question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597570/putting-rails-over-top-of-an-existing-database