# Rails use MS SQL server database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

In my rails app, I need to use an existing MS SQL database. I have tried following this manual:

http://rubyrailsandwindows.blogspot.com/2008/03/rails-2-and-sql-server-2008-on-windows_24.html

I do not know how to do models, scaffolds, etc because rails cannot simply use another db. I didn't want to run rake db:migrate for my tables in the MS SQL database. What else do I need to write in the model?
If simple: use tables from the MS SQL server's database, but I also want to solve problem with migrations, etc.

Comment: Are you wanting to hook Rails up to an existing database, or a new one?

Comment: @Snips yes: to connect to existing mssql...

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597570/putting-rails-over-top-of-an-existing-database

Comment: @mccannf it is not exactly what i need... becouse from this existing mssql db i need generate fields in view too, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run your Rails up on top of the existing database and you want to make sure you can create all models that match existing tables, follow this guide:

- Dump the schema into schema.rb using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you.  I would actually use SQL mode of schema (`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` ) and just use SQL Server tools to generate SQL file of the database schema and preserve it as `db/structure.sql`
- After the database schema has been established, you can redirect tables and primary keys in your models using an approach outlined here: [Putting Rails over top of an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597570/putting-rails-over-top-of-an-existing-database)

As an alternative to ActiveRecord altogether, you might consider [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/why.html) as it claims to work better with "brownfield" (i.e. already established) databases.

Comment: Yes, and then for each model you create, you can run `rails generate scaffold_controller ModelName` to auto create controllers and views.

Comment: but will then i need to write all relations in models? has many, belongs?

Comment: also i need to create all models?