# Using ruby on rails with SQL Server mixed case database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am trying to use SQL Server with ruby on rails.  I created a test table and it did not work until I made the table and field names all lower case.  The database I wish to use is quite large and if I made everything lowercase it would be terrible as far as readability goes.  Someone suggested to use 'lowercase_schema_reflection' but they told me to add it to my config/initializers file for the adapter.  I do not have one so if anyone know how to implement this I would appreciate it if they could tell me.

Solution:
Steve found the solution in the comments and did not make a post so I will provide the solution here.

He pointed out that I needed to do a rake db:schema:dump.  Although it still did not work properly.  The Table in the database is "EMP".  The rake command calls it "emp".  So in the model the line "self.table_name = 'EMP'", as accurate as it is, still fails.  It needs to be "self.table_name = 'emp'".  I am truly surprised a modern framework is case-sensitive (a mistake in any programming language design) let alone be inconsistent in its case-sensitivity.  This error in design has cost me many hours and I am sure I am not the only one.  Lets hope any developers designing any language and / or frameworks in the future avoid this costly mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613574/how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-models-table-name-mapping-in-rails.  Essentially, you can follow Rails conventions in your codebase and then add `self.table_name = ...` to link your code to your actual database table names.

Comment: Tried that.  It does not work.

Comment: Not sure what didn't work but if you want to use the option you mentioned in your email, just create a new file in `config/initializers` (e.g. `active_record.rb`) and put in this line of code:  `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true`.  Restart Rails, run any migrations and you should be good to go.

Comment: What did not work was getting data from a table.  All I am trying to do is test the data connection and it fails.  I do not have any migrations, all the data and schema already exists in the database.  self.table_name is being ignored as well.

Comment: Did you try the initializer?  If so, what did you specifically access and what response did you get?  I would try to access using Rails console initially.

Comment: I did use the console.  Thats what produced the error message.  I put this code in config\initializers\active_record.rb: 
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true
ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = 'dbo.'
Tried it with or without the second line.  Still fails.  Its too bad because this seems like a good framework.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry, thought I posted it.   Employee(Table doesn't exist)

Comment: I have never heard of Rails ActiveRecord working without migrations.  I thought they were required.

Comment: What is a migration according to ruby?  Everytime I have done a migration it included moving data from one database to another.  I have an existing database and nothing to migrate unless ruby uses an unconventional use of the word.  I am looking at this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html but all the examples are modifying something.  I do'nt have anything to modify.  Do I have to create a table just so I can run a modification?  Do I just make up any kind of change?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597570/putting-rails-over-top-of-an-existing-database)?  Maybe it will help you.  In Rails, migrations are used for database structure as often (or more frequently) than database data.  I would recommend you use `rake db:schema:dump` to generate a schema file which will serve to synchronize your Rails components (models, views, controllers, helpers, etc) with your actual DB schema.  Then, use Rails migrations going forward for any schema changes.

Comment: Thanks Steve!!  That was something I needed.  I posted the complete solution above.

Comment: Glad I was able to help @Joe.