# Cant connect to SQL server database with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am having a hard time connection to my SQL Server 2005 data on a Windows 7 machine.

I created a table and model following ruby's standards and can connect with the console and get the field names.  I can not get it to work with any existing tables.

I created this model which does not work:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

    set_table_name = 'EMP'
    primary_key = 'EMP_EmployeeID'

end
```

However if I add a table called employees with a primary key of 'id' the model works, albeit taking the fields from the table I added and ignoring the real table.

Any one have any clue on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code::::

```
self.table_name = "EMP"
self.primary_key = "EMP_EmployeeID"
```

set_table_name and primary_key, does not imply anything

Comment: Made the change and I still get this:  Employee(Table doesn't exist).  I even tried self.table_name = 'dbo.EMP' but that did not work either.

Comment: your table name is EMP not Employee

Comment: Yes, thats what I tried to explain to you.  The table name is EMP.  The model is Employee.  When you use the rails console you use the class name NOT the table name.  When I tried to instantiate the class Employee which maps to table EMP I received the error "Table doesn't exist".  Fortunately Steve Klein pointed out the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463738/using-ruby-on-rails-with-sql-server-mixed-case-database